# P4V Path '/Applications/...' is not under client's root '/Users/sylwester/test'

Tags: perforce, p4v

I've set up a new workspace in `/Users/sylwester/test` and checked for get all revisions and switch to workspace. Every time i start p4v and select my workspace after login I get this error. The command it says it has performed is:

```
p4 changes -s submitted -l -m 100 /Applications/...
```

The p4v executable is of course in the `/Applications/` directory but my workspace in `/Users/sylwester/test`. To be sure it was not fixed at a later version i upgraded p4v to 2017.2 (P4V/MACOSX1011X86_64/2017.2/1518788)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a filter somewhere (probably the history or submitted changelists tab?) that specifies `/Applications/...` as the path.  If you clear or fix that I'd expect the error to go away.